# Basic property of a simplest fibered product

Tags: category-theory

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be sets and let $\phi:X_2\to X_1$ be a map.

The identity map $\text{id}:X_1\to X_1$ along with the map $\phi:X_2\to X_1$ gives rise to the fibered product (in the category of sets) $(X, f_1, f_2)$ where $f_1:X\to X_1$ and $f_2:X\to X_2$ are such that $\phi\circ f_2 = f_1$ and a familiar universal property is satisfied.

Consider a concrete realization of the fibered product given by
$$
X = \{(x_2, x_1)\in X_2\times X_1:\ \phi(x_2) = x_1 \}
$$
and $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the coordinate projection maps.

**Here is my problem.** Given a map $\alpha:X\to Y$, where $Y$ is any set, we can define a map $\beta:X_2\to Y$ as
$$
\beta(x_2) = \alpha(x_2, \phi(x_2))
$$
So we have a 'natural' map $\hom(X, Y) \to \hom(X_2, Y)$ for any set $Y$.

*I am not able to get such a map abstractly, that is, by only using the universal property of the fibered product.*

Comment: It suffices to give a morphism in the case where $Y = X$ and $\alpha = \textrm{id}_X$ – the general case follows by naturality.

Comment: I get it, thanks. There is a natural map from $X_2$ to $X$ coming from the fibered product property. Perhaps you can write an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1):

In general, for any morphism $f: Z \rightarrow X$ you get a map $\hom(X, Y) \rightarrow \hom(Z, Y)$ sending any $\alpha$ to $\alpha \circ f$.

Here you are in the case of $Z = X_2$ and $f: Z \rightarrow X$ sends $x_2$ to $(x_2, \phi(x_2))$. This doesn't involve any property of the fiber product.

Note that usually one only has structural morphisms from a fiber product to its factors. Here however one of the fibers is identity (an isomorphism), thus it also lifts into an isomorphism. More precisely, we have the following:

**Lemma**: If $\alpha \in \hom(A, C)$ is an isomorphism, then for any $\beta\in \hom(B, C)$, the fiber product $D = A \times _C B$ is isomorphic to $B$ via the structural map $\gamma \in \hom(D, B)$.

**Proof**: Apply the universal property to $\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta\in \hom(B, A)$ and $id \in \hom(B, B)$ to get an inverse map in $\hom(B, D)$.

The map $f$ here is nothing but the inverse isomorphism.